# Не работает привязка к Image.Source WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

```
<Window x:Class="project.View.AddWorkerWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:project.View"
        xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:project.Helpers"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="AddWorkerWindow" Height="626.582" Width="831.899">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local1:ImgSourceConverter x:Key="ImgSourceConverter"></local1:ImgSourceConverter>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image
               Margin="0 40 0 0"
               Source="{Binding ImgFile, Converter={StaticResource ImgSourceConverter}}"
               Height="200"
               Width="200"
                />
```

Свойство во `ViewModel`

```
private string imgFile;

public string ImgFile
{
   get { return imgFile; }
   set
   {
       imgFile = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged();
   }
 }
```

Инициализирую свойство `ImgFile` в конструкторе `ViewModel`
`ImgFile = "../images/man.png";`
При запуске приложения картинка не отображается. 
Когда меняю свойство `ImgFile` - аналогично

Вставляю тот же путь в тег `<Image>` `Source="../images/man.png"` - картинка видна

*В чем может быть причина?*

Comment: на другом окне та же реализация работает. у меня в базе хранятся имена файлов, а `ImgSourceConverter` просто добавляет в начало входной строки `../images/

Comment: странно, если у вас так работает; [например](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.image.source?view=netframework-4.7.2#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: объект контекста данных задали?

Comment: да, задал `this.DataContext = new AddWorkerViewModel()`

Comment: Зачем нужен `ImgSourceConverter`? WPF умеет конвертировать `string` в `ImageSource` автоматически.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой Image находлися в ListView и при подстановке в Source пути из бд (строка), картинка не выводилась. Помогла конвертация в байт код и инициализация BitMap

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            if (value != null)
            {
                string part = (string)value;
                string path = @"..\..\images\" + part;
                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                byte[] rawImageData = null;

                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    rawImageData = new byte[fs.Length];
                    int count = (int)fs.Length / 1024;
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                        fs.Read(rawImageData, i*1024, 1024);
                    int last = (int)(fs.Length - count * 1024);
                    fs.Read(rawImageData, count*1024, last);
                }

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(rawImageData))
                {

                    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                    bitmapImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
                    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;

                    bitmapImage.EndInit();
                }
                return bitmapImage;
            }
            return null;
        }
```